# Implementing simple group chat in Android

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I'm currently working on an application that uses google maps to create Chat session.So my App will create a particular chat session only for the user's who are currently visible on google maps.
Which is the best way to do this either using webservices or Sockets??? and how to achieve this??

I've read about XMPP protocol but still don't have idea how to go further with this.Any documentation or tutorial will be a great help.

Comment: Google has documentation about that over http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

Comment: a comment I can make but you may want to investigate is that you cannot make serversockets on mobile phones when a user is using 3G (data-roaming). You'll probably need a "middle man" for sockets

Comment: I've used GCM already in one of my app,i know its for push notification,but how to make use of it when it comes to instant messaging?? @Saqib

Comment: Can you refer me some tutorial to achieve this functionality??? @Losin'Me

Comment: I can't right now; however maybe look into communication between server sockets in Java if you want your chat to be live.
However, you'll likely need a server to connect to as phones cannot host servers as far as i'm aware (not using serversockets).